# LINQ: query returns list of empty objects

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-dataset

I have a query that 'selects' object of a type:

```
Dim l as IList(Of Foo) = (From dataRow As DataRow In table.Select()
                          Where CStr(dataRow("Column1")) = "A"
                          Select New Foo(CStr(dataRow("Column1")), _
                                         CStr(dataRow("Column2")))).ToList()
```

What's happening is that if i set a break-point to the constructor of `Foo` and step, the constructor is hit and the parameters are loaded with the arguments. However, `l` has empty `Foo` objects (the members in every object are `Nothing`). What could be happening here?

Comment: It sounds like `Foo` isn't storing the values of the parameters to the constructor.  Can you post the constructor as well?

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to :

```
Dim l as IList(Of Foo) = (From dataRow As DataRow In table..AsEnumerable()
                          Where datarow.Field(of String)("Column1") = "A" 
                          Select New Foo(datarow.Field(of String)("Column1"), _
                                         datarow.Field(of String)("Column1"))).ToList()
```

for more informations you can visit [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688086) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/81417/Linq-To-Dataset-Display-the-Contents-of-Several-Ta)